# PDF stopped being updated when latex document is compiled

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texmaker

I use texmaker to make my latex documents, and normally it works fine. But now I am working on a file that has stopped updating the PDF document when I use my quick build (PDFlatex + view latex). My tex file was recently modified today and the PDF file was recently modified when I worked on the document last time. No errors occur when I compile my latex document

How do I get an updated PDF file?

Now I have commented out everything such that my document is like:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12 pt, danish] {article} 
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc} 
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc} 
\usepackage {babel} 

\begin{document} 
small text 
\end{document}
```

And it still does not seem as if anything happens when I press PDFlatex. If you need more information please tell me which then I will try to provide them,

Best regards Lone

Comment: I think we need a little more information....if it is caused just by this particular file try commenting out more and more parts of it to try and determine what is causing the problem

Comment: Please update your question with that information instead. Did you try restarting TeXMaker? Does it fire up `pdflatex` if you press F6?

Comment: It does not change anything when i restart TexMaker, and when i press F6 i can see that the program tries to do something, but nothing happens. The PDF document is still an old version from another day.

Comment: Then we start from the basics. Which operating system are you on?

Comment: Windows 7 32bit

Comment: Just for the fun of it, have you tried a reboot? Or, have you tried making a brand new file, with the content from the MWE you posted and then see if that compiles.

Comment: Which LaTeX installation? TeX Live or MikTeX? And which version

Comment: It is texlive, but i am not sure how to see which version it is.

Comment: Turned out to be a system problem, where a PATH setting was presumably overwritten removing TeX Live.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a system problem removing access to relevant binaries (see comments).